# How to convert from string to object of any type?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I need to convert from a string that contains data to an object of some type that is passed using reflection. I have a not-serializable object that contains properties of any type, and I want to load data to that object.

For example, that object has a property, `Color BgColor`. When I am trying to set "Red" value to that property, I get that conversion is not possible from string to Color. I need general code.

Comment: Consider [Generalized Type Conversion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy580hbd.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [`Convert.ChangeType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.changetype.aspx) for general conversions.

But in your case I think the [`Color.FromName`](http://Color.FromName) method would be best:

> Creates a Color structure from the specified name of a predefined color.

Comment: No unfortunately I know about it, and it doesn't help, Can it convert 120 to System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit for example? in xml I have a string and the width property type is   Unit

Comment: Is there a general method? Or I should use switch case or try to find parse method by reflection?

Answer (score 0):

If all you need to do is convert a string to its value in an `enum`, you can use code similar to the following:

```
public static T ToEnum<T>(this string original)
{
    Array values = Enum.GetValues(typeof(T));

    foreach (T value in values)
    {
        if (value.ToString().ToUpperInvariant() == original.ToUpperInvariant())
            return value;
    }

    throw new NotFoundException();
}
```

If you need to convert other types, then perhaps specifying types and the formats of the string might help people direct you better.

Comment: the property type is not an enum always, I am loading ASP.NET controls from xml and want to set all control properties from xml values, but ASP.NET somehow converts 129 px string to UNit type, in my case I get an error